# Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker not calling customclass

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I ham having an issue with angular ui-bootstraps datepicker 
It refuses to call custom class wether its supplied through datepicker-options options or the custom-class attribute

code below

Jade

```
div(uib-datepicker
  ng-model="data.report_end"
  show-weeks="false"                
  width='300'
  min-date ="data.report_start"
  datepicker-options= "end_model_options" 
  ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"
```

Coffeescript

```
scope.end_model_options =
 timezone : 'UTC',
 debounce :300,
 minDate:scope.report_start.utc().toDate() ,
 customClass: scope.getDayClass

scope.getDayClass = (date, mode) ->
 console.log 'getDayClass'
 if mode == 'day'
 dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
 i = 0
 while i < scope.events.length
    currentDay = new Date(scope.events[i].date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
    if dayToCheck == currentDay
      return scope.events[i].status
      i++
      return
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the ui-bootstrap datepicker says that the customClass key expects an object. Looking through the source code confirms this. There is likely no way to pass a function as an object and expect it to execute.

Comment: The plunker with the source code has a function being used is there something i am missing? [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) (sorry it wont let me edit the previous comment)